# Jackket service won't start : error 1064

Tags: windows-10, services, jackett

I have Jackcett installed, but it won't start.

[image]

Any ideas how to correct this?

Answer (score 0):

My friend had the same problem and we fixed it by updating the .NET framework to the latest version. According to the Jackett git hub, you need version Windows using .NET 4.6.1 or above.

Comment: Thanks, but I have version 4.8.04084 :-(

Comment: Hmmm...Ok make sure the locally created id on the eminentware server dose have permission to logon as a service.  Since after adding the local id to your default domain policy in GPO as an id with permission to logon as a service everything should be working fine.

Comment: Could you explain a little more? What is `local Id`?